# angular JS select first instance of this item

Tags: angularjs, json

So my question is: how do I scan the JSON in angular to find the first instance of isPrimary:true and then launch a function with the GUID that is in that item.

I have a webservice whos JSON defines available Accounts with a display name and a GUID this generates a dropdown select list that calls a function with the GUID included to return full data from a web service.

In the scenario where theres only 1 OPTION I dont show the SELECT and simply call the function with the single GUID to return the data from the service. If theres no options I dont show anything other than a message.

Code below shows what I currently have.

The Spec has now changed and the data they are sending me in the first service call which defines that select list is now including a property isPrimary:true on one of the JSON object along with its GUID as per the rest

I now need to change my interface to no longer use the SELECT list and instead fire the function call to the service for the item that contains the isPrimary:true property. However there may be multiple instances where isPrimary:true exists in the returning JSON so I just want to fire the function on the first found instance of isPrimary:true

Equally if that property isnt in any of the JSON items then just fire the function on the first item in the JSON.

My current Code is below - you can see the call to retrieve the full details is from function:

```
vm.retrieveAccount(GUID);
```

Where the GUID is supplied with each JSON object

Code is:

```
if (data.Accounts.length > 1) {
            vm.hideAcc = false;
            setBusyState(false);
            //wait for the user to make a selection
        } else if (data.Accounts.length == 1){
            vm.hideAcc = true;                
            // Only 1 acc - no need for drop down get first item
            vm.accSelected = data.Accounts[0].UniqueIdentifier;
            vm.retrieveAccount(vm.accSelected);

        } else {
            // Theres no accounts
            // Hide Drop down and show message
            setBusyState(false);
            vm.hideAcc = true;
            setMessageState(false, true, "There are no Accounts")
        }
```

Sample of new JSON structure

accName: "My Acc",
isPrimary: true,
GUID: "bg111010101"

Comment: People are having a hard time understanding what you are asking.  Any chance you can mock out in code where you want help with?  e.g. //this is what i can't figure out

Comment: Where is `isPrimary` attached to the data? What does the rest of the data structure look like?

Comment: (Incidentally that sounds like a really bizarre spec: here's a list of options, automatically pick the first one that has a flag, unless there are no flags, in which case just automatically pick the first one --- why even send the list to the client instead of just sending the one that should be automatically picked?)

Comment: hmm out of context perhaps but this is a list of available accounts for a user to choose from - if that user has nominated one of their accounts to be their primary one so when they load the site it is their preferred screen then it defaults a selects that. Equally if they havent opted for that feature we have to load something so we chose the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still think that's a weird spec, but simple enough to solve. Just step through the array and return the first isPrimary match. If none are found, return the first element of the array.

```
var findPrimary = function(data) {
  if (!(Array.isArray(data)) || data.length == 0) {
    return false;  // not an array, or empty array
  }
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].isPrimary) {
      return data[i]; // first isPrimary match
    }
  }
  // nothing had isPrimary, so return the first one:
  return data[0];
}
```